# Startup script fails

Tags: bash, startup, ubuntu-mate

This runs fine as standalone, but fails (Seamonkey does not start) when used as a startup application.

```
sleep 5 && seamonkey
```

I am using this to add programs to my startup.

```
mate-session-properties
```

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Define 'fails'.

Comment: It does not start Seamonkey. @DopeGhoti

Comment: Rather than give a very small subset of what it does _not_ do (e. g. the intended start of Seamonkey), please describe in verbose and complete detail what it _does_ do (e. g. it presents an error stating "such-and-such").

Comment: Why do you need to "sleep 5" ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting the commands into a bash script which is in my Startup Applications Preferences.